# Programmatically segue from UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, swift, segue, selector, uibarbuttonitem

I have three view controllers, all with two buttons each on the right and left sides of the navigation bar, as seen below on one of them.

[image: Example VC]

I'm creating these buttons programatically, and instead of writing the code in each respective view controller (VC) I decided to write a Helper class that creates the buttons.

```
// Note: I am using FontAwesome as a third-party library.

class Helper: NSObject {

    static func loadNavBarItems(vc: UIViewController) {
        let profileButton = UIBarButtonItem()
        let addButton = UIBarButtonItem()

        let attributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.fontAwesome(ofSize: 20)] as [String: Any]

        profileButton.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: .normal)
        addButton.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, for: .normal)

        profileButton.title = String.fontAwesomeIcon(name: .userCircle)
        addButton.title = String.fontAwesomeIcon(name: .plus)

        vc.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = profileButton
        vc.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton
    }

    func segueToProfile(vc: UIViewController) { // I need help here. }

}
```

I then call `Helper.loadNavBarItems(vc: self)` from each VC's `viewDidLoad()`.

What I'm trying to do now is to trigger a segue when one of the buttons is pressed (let's assume it's the profile button). So, I need to define `profile.action`. So, in the Helper class, I have to write a function `segueToProfile` that takes a view contoller (`vc`) and runs `performSegueWithIdentifier`.

The problem is, I'm not fully understanding how to pass in different types of parameters through selectors, and I may be bad at Googling but I cannot find any questions that are close enough to mine for me to understand how to achieve this.

Many thanks in advance for your help.

For reference, [this is the structure of my Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9W3nJ.jpg).

**EDIT:** As shown in the storyboard structure screenshot, I've already created a segue from each of the three view controllers to the destination view controller.

Comment: What kind of parameters through selector you're willing to send? Also in your storyboard mock, you're presenting navigation controller. So you should understand that the destinationController gonna be the NavigationController, not the ViewCotnroller. Another thing is that probably you should create an extension for UIViewController and replace all that code of creating and assigning BarButtons into it. That way you avoid passing UIViewController parameter into `loadNavBarItems` func

Comment: @noir_eagle Thanks, but my problem is with understanding UIBarButtonItem actions and selectors. I'm trying to trigger a segue when one of the UIBarButtonItems are tapped, and I'm trying to figure out how to pass in parameters to a selector when using `profileButton.action`

Comment: Is this navigation controller with those buttons on every page? Or just one ViewController?

Comment: The buttons are on every view controller (type `UIViewController`) which is nested inside a Navigation Controller.

Answer (score 1):

To create barButtonItem:

```
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(ProfileButtonTapped))
```

To create action and segue for barButtonItem:

```
 func ProfileButtonTapped() { 
    print("Button Tapped")   
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "YourSegueIdentifierName", sender: self) 
    //If you want pass data while segue you can use prepare segue method
   }
```

**Note :** To `perform segue` you have to give `segue identifier name` from your storyboard.

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

**Updated:**

If you want to connect your destVC without segue you can use below method:

Note: To use below method you have to set `storyBoard Id` in `identity inspector`.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let DestVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DestVcName") as! DestVcName //UINavigationController
self.present(DestVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if i understand your problem, but for passing data between viewControllers(embedded in a `UINavigationController` in your case) using segue, you can do it in:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
  if(segue.identifier == "yourIdentifier"){
        let navPreview : UINavigationController = segue.destination as! UINavigationController
        let preview : YourViewController = navPreview.viewControllers[0] as! YourViewController
}}
```

Comment: Thanks Alessio, but my problem is with UIBarButtonItem actions and selectors. I'm trying to trigger a segue when one of the UIBarButtonItems are tapped.

Comment: ok, but have you problems to trigger segue for a new controller ? because in this case, from storyboard, you can use control+drag to your controller and check on (Relationship segue (view controllers)) and automatically Xcode creates a single segue from tabbarController to UIViewController

Answer (score 0):

To add an action to a `UIBarButton` you should use one of its initializers. 
For example

```
let profileButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Your title", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector("Call your function to push View controller"))
```

Instead of title , you can also set an Image to that button.

Comment: Thanks, but can you show me how to add an action that takes in a parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You can create barButtonItems with selectors :

```
 let leftBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: image, landscapeImagePhone: image, style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.bordered, target: self, action: #selector(didPressLeftButton))
```

Where the didPressLeftButton is a function :

```
 func didPressLeftButton(){
        print("Did press left button")
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, but can you show me how to add an action that takes in a parameter?

Comment: Have a look at the tutorial here, they have a couple good examples with parameters :https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/hannibal-selector/

Comment: Just another thought @FaresK.A. - do you actually need to pass parameters? If every view has its own navigation buttons, maybe attach the functionality didPressLeft, didPressRight to the view controller. To make it more reusable, you could subclass it with a base view controller that would handle creating the buttons.