# Unable to add target and run function on UIBarButtonItem click in iOS Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibarbuttonitem

I'm unable to detect on-click events on `UIBarButtonItems` in `Swift 3`. Can anyone help?. I need to perform a `segue` to another storyboard and `view controller` on clicking the `UIBarButtonItem`.

Comment: Please upload your code and upload your "debug view hierarchy" image ?

Comment: Could you elaborate? @martinlee mentioned a good point...

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40891119/programmatically-segue-from-uibarbuttonitem/40892465#40892465

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swift 3.0:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   let controllerButton: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem.init(title: "Next", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.changeController))
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = controllerButton
  }

func changeController() {
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "Controller name segue", sender: AnyObject) 
}
```

Please check this above code to for creating UIBarButtonItem and keep that on right navigation Item along with target and action.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout sample code below:-

```
var b = UIBarButtonItem(
    title: "Continue",
    style: .plain,
    target: self,
    action: #selector(sayHello(sender:))
)

func sayHello(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
}
```