# UIBarButtonItem is not working swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift

I have a Navigation controller and I'm trying to put a button on the right of navigation bar but I can't handle the tap action. I'm declaring the UIBarButtonItem like this

```
let navigationButton = UIBarButtonItem.init(title: "Logout", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(RestaurantsListViewController.logoutAction))
```

I'm adding the button on the viewDidLoad func

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = navigationButton
}
```

and the function that I'm trying to use to handle the tap event is this

```
func logoutAction(sender: AnyObject?){
    print("Logout")
}
```

but when I press the button, the message is not printed in console.

Comment: let navigationButton = UIBarButtonItem.init(title: "Logout", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(RestaurantsListViewController.logoutAction)) is in the view did load ..?

Comment: In which controller you have written logoutAction function?

Comment: @AnilKumar I have the initializer on the main class, out of all methods

Comment: @BalajiGalave I have all in the same view controller

Comment: Then try my posted answer below. And one thing try to set button for Navigationbar in viewWillAppear method of view controller. Thats good place to add.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40891119/programmatically-segue-from-uibarbuttonitem/40892465#40892465

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "ButtonName", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(YourViewController.yourAction))

}
```

Comment: Initialize UIBarButtonItem inside viewDidLoad func fix the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
  let okbtn = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.logoutAction))
```

Try This
otherwise You need to replace func like

```
func logoutAction()
{
  print("logout")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is when you create `navigationButton` as a class property, it gets initialized *before* `self` is initialized. So `self` doesn't exist yet when you pass it in as the `target` of the button.

There are a couple ways to fix it, including the answer by @Mannopson where you initialize the button inside the `viewDidLoad`, which ensures that `self` has already been created.

Another way to solve this issue is to declare `navigationButton` to be a `lazy var`:

```
lazy var navigationButton = UIBarButtonItem.init(title: "Logout", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(RestaurantsListViewController.logoutAction))
```

The `lazy var` ensures that the property only gets initialized when the property gets accessed (hence it being a lazy initialization). Since the first time it is accessed happens in `viewDidLoad`, we can also be sure that `self` has been created. Hope this gives you more context!