# Swift Segue from UIBarButtonItem

Tags: swift, xcode, segue

I have made many segues before, but never from a UIBarButtonItem.

I just cannot figure out what's wrong whit this on. I keep getting the same error. libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException.

I dont want to pass any data with this segue, just displaying the controller.

What do I do wrong ?????

```
                let badge = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 10, width: 20, height: 20))
                badge.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
                badge.layer.borderWidth = 2
                badge.layer.cornerRadius = badge.bounds.size.height / 2
                badge.textAlignment = .center
                badge.layer.masksToBounds = true
                badge.textColor = .white
                badge.font = UIFont(name: "AppleSDGothicNeo-Medium", size: 12)
                badge.backgroundColor = .red
                badge.text = "\(snapshot.childrenCount.description)"

                let navBarFollowBtn = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 35, height: 35))
                navBarFollowBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "profileNewFollower"), for: .normal)
                navBarFollowBtn.addTarget(self, action: Selector(("navigateToNextViewController")), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

                navBarFollowBtn.addSubview(badge)

                let barBtn = self.navBarNewFollower
                barBtn?.customView = navBarFollowBtn
                self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barBtn
                 //                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "newFollowerSegue", sender: self)

            } else {

                self.navBarNewFollower.isEnabled = true
                }
            })
        }

    setUpBadgeCountNewFollowers()

//Segue to NewFollowers
    func navigateToNextViewController() {
        print("Button Tapped")
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "newFollowerSegue", sender: self)

    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40891119/programmatically-segue-from-uibarbuttonitem/40892465#40892465

Comment: Does not work. Have tried that

Comment: Could you show the whole error? It has often clues about the issue.

Comment: Where's the rest of the error?

Comment: Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Comment: In the console where you got "nating with uncaught exception of type NSException." there is no more message?

Answer (score 0):

You've got double parenthesis in your selector, guess that's the issue:

```
        navBarFollowBtn.addTarget(self, action: Selector(("navigateToNextViewController")), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
```

for swift 4 change it to:

```
navBarFollowBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(navigateToNextViewController), for: .touchUpInside)

@objc func navigateToNextViewController() {
        print("Button Tapped")
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "newFollowerSegue", sender: self)
    }
```

Comment: Does not work. Xcode keeps changing the code to my code